# Kernelized Probabilistic Matrix Factorization - Implementation?

Tags: python, matrix-factorisation

I am trying to implement a kernelized probabilistic matrix factorization which is mentioned in this paper. [KPMF Paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/39b3/7be59bf4784a3b7af631755ae03d87c91a61.pdf). I have coded two update functions as two separate methods. I don't know if this is a correct implementation or not. Can somebody help me understand if the implementation is correct? Below are the two functions:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial U_{n,d}} = -\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{m=1}^{M}\delta_{n,m}(R_{n,m}-U_{n,:}V^T_{m,:})V_{d,m} + e^T_nS_UU_{:,d}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial E}{\partial U_{n,d}} = -\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\delta_{n,m}(R_{n,m}-U_{n,:}V^T_{m,:})U_{d,n} + e^T_mS_VV_{:,d}
\end{equation}

```
 def run_U(self,U,V,R,en,su):
    Uhat = np.zeros(U.shape)
    for i in range(U.shape[0]):
        en.fill(0)
        for z in range(U.shape[1]):
            fty = 0
            en[0,i] = 1
            gty = (en.dot(su)).dot(U[:,z])
            for k in range(len(V)):
                if R[i,k] != 0:
                    fty += (R[i,k] - (U[i,:].dot((V[k,:]).T)))*(V[k,z].T)
                else:
                    fty = 0
            Uhat[i,z] = gty+fty
    return Uhat

def run_V(self,U,V,R,em,sv):
    Vhat = np.zeros(V.shape)
    for i in range(V.shape[0]):
        em.fill(0)
        for z in range(V.shape[1]):
            fty = 0
            em[0,i] = 1
            gty = (em.dot(sv)).dot(V[:,z])
            for k in range(len(U)):
                if R[k,i] != 0:
                    fty += (R[k,i] - (U[k,:].dot((V[i,:]).T)))*(U[k,z].T)
                else:
                    fty = 0
            Vhat[i,z] = gty + fty
    return Vhat
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would help if you add a summary of the parameters in the equation (what they represent) in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. $\delta_{n,m}$ is an identifier and $R$,$U$,$V$ are matrices. $e_n$ and $e_m$ are unit vectors and $S_u$ and $S_v$ are matrices as well. Does that help or do you need the size of the matrices as well? The model works but I can't validate them because it's a new dataset that I have been working on. There's no baseline. I can tell that it works better than basic MF technique.